# Eslint throws exception when multiple variables are declared as global

Tags: node.js, undefined, eslint

Here is code for my js file

```
import { Selector } from 'testcafe'

/* global fixture:true, test:true */
fixture`index`
.page`http://localhost:8080`

test('Index Page Loads', async t => {
await t
// Check for h1 tag
.expect(Selector('#root h1').innerText).eql('Hello')

})
```

When I run lint it throws exception

```
ReferenceError: fixture is not defined
at Object.fixture
```

Comment: Might be a better way, but might you just declare them on separate lines?

Comment: Tried that still same issue